# SASS - apply existing class to another element

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Sorry if this is in the SASS docs - I am not sure what its called and not finding it. I am converting a LESS project to SASS and ran across some issues. In LESS everything is a mixin so I can just do:

```
.myclass {
  border: red;
}
.another {
 .myclass();
}
```

How do I do this in SASS? I have tried @include but thats a no go. Making a mixin is out of the question as the `myclass` is in a bower imported file.

Comment: Ok - SASS cannot do this evidently. There is a limited @extend directive but can't achieve what LESS can  Seems to be 5+ issues opened on this. https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/501

Comment: this is possible, the answer in the duplicate genuinely does answer your question, we use `@extend` in sass to load stuff from another class

Comment: @ToniLeigh - extend generally works but not in my case - it just threw errors. This posts explains the issue. http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-extend-nobody-told-you/

Comment: what errors did it throw?

Comment: `@extends` is a headache though, fools gold, Harry Roberts at CSSWizardry probably describes how to use it well and not overdo it: http://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/

Comment: `You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.` was the error. Its not biggy. In less I extend my classes all over the places from the Bootstrap so I am kind of bound by that process. Its completely effortless to do it in less. I was considering switching to use Jekyll on GH but I gave up on that entire platform so the issue is no big deal anymore

Comment: you weren't in a media query?